# Listing Persons of a Certain Occupation using PersonData

Tags: version-10, entity

I am trying to generate a list of people that Mathematica knows about that have a certain occupation.

Using the `PersonData[]` command I can get a list of all 285,362 people that Mathematica knows about. For a specific person `Entity`, I can use `PersonData` to learn more about them. For example, `PersonData[Entity["Person", "LebronJames::tv6s9"], EntityProperty["Person", "Occupation"]]` tells me that Lebron James is a basketball player.

I'm trying to filter this list of 285,362 people to a list of people that are basketball players.

1. Is there a way to download this information from the Cloud without downloading all 286,000 data points first?
2. If not, how can I use a `Select` function call or something to filter the `PersonData[]` list by occupation?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a bug with `"Person"`. `EntityValue[EntityClass["Person",
 {"Occupation" -> "basketball player"}], "EntityCount"]` should return the number of `"Person"` entities that have `"basketball player"` in their `"Occupation"` list.  However it returns zero.  Please report to WRI.

Comment: It works for `EntityValue[
 EntityClass["Person", {"Gender" -> "Male"}], "EntityCount"]` so I'm more inclined to think it is a bug.

Comment: @Edmund is there a way to return the entire list of entities, not just the count?

Comment: See [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue.html).  `EntityValue[ EntityClass["Person", {"Gender" -> "Male"}], "Entities"]`

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's no way to access this data in Mathematica 10 without filtering it and resolving your own list. I've produced a list of all basketball players (albeit in several hours) using the following code:

```
people = PersonData[]; (* over 500,000 Entities representing people *)

isBasketballPlayer[p_] := Module[{occupation},
  (occupation = PersonData[p, "Occupation"];
   If[
    MatchQ[occupation, _Missing],
    False, 
    MemberQ[occupation, "basketball player"]
    ])]; 

basketballPlayers = Select[people, isBasketballPlayer]
```